# Can I run a 32bit binary in a 64bit docker container on a 64bit only host kernel?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a docker host machine with the following kernel according to `uname -a`:

```
Linux 4.4.30-unRAID #2 SMP PREEMPT Sat Nov 5 12:09:05 PDT 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1265L V2 @ 2.50GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

This kernel is a 64 bit only kernel as far as I know. But I do need to run a 32bit binary inside of a docker container on this host. Since all containers share their kernel this is not possible so far.

Is there any trick with with I could enable the container to run this 32bit binary despite this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can, but you'll need to install 32-bit libraries to container

Comment: I've read about that too. I installed these libraries: libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386. But im still not able to execute the binary. I heard that the trick with the libs only works on kernels which have a 32bit compatibility layer, which the unRAID kernel does not have as far as I know.